# how to store and retrieve dictonary in sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, django

I am getting this type result from query object:

```
report_qs = CustomReport.objects.all().filter(id=report_id)

[<CustomReport: {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}>]
```

**CustomReport Model:**

```
class CustomReport(models.Model):
    """
        Save the result of the custom report form wizard for further
        regeneration. The result is saved as a serialized dictionary.
    """

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('creation_date', 'name'),)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    query = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now,
                                         editable=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.query
```

How to get values and keys?

Comment: Add your CustomReport model.

Comment: i have added  this line   "from models import CustomReport" in view file

Comment: Add it to this post...

Answer (score 0):

You Should try

```
report_qs = CustomReport.objects.all().filter(id=report_id).values('name', 'age', 'class')
```

Now see report_qs  you can easily get values and keys.
You can iterate report_qs

```
for obj in report_qs:
    print obj.keys()
    print obj.values()
```

Comment: i think dic parameters are coming from models.py .  ??? let me know if i am wrong

Comment: its not working for me..., dictionary store in sqlit3 database

Comment: AttributeError: 'CustomReport' object has no attribute 'keys'